# Unable to save the redirect/callbacl url in Jira oauth authentication

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

In Jira application when we give the redirect/callback URL with port number 443 and save it I'm getting this error:
Updating callback URL failed. Protocol must consist of alpha-numeric characters, dashes and dots.
Please find the screenshot of this error below:

[Jira callback error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZL7w.png)

I tried giving the callback/redirect URL https://instance url:443/icsapis/agent/oauth/callback and save it I'm getting the error.
But when I give the redirect URL https://instance url:other than 443 or without any port number/icsap/agent/callback and save it I'm able to save.

Answer (score 0):

This is because HTTPS defaults to port 443. Does it work if you enter the following:

```
https://soa136.becone.com/icapis/agent/oauth/callba...
```

Don't include port number if it is the default port.

Comment: Hi,
We have tried without including the port number we are able to save. But we are unable to get authenticated while we direct the user to the authorization URL to get an authorization code. So we need to add :443 port number.

Comment: Is there any other way to resolve this issue?